# What type of bonding is present in lithium tetrahydridoaluminate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, ionic-compounds, covalent-compounds

I can tell that the negative ion has one bond which is a co-ordinate/dative covalent bond.

However, overall, would you say that lithium tetrahydridoaluminate (lithium aluminium hydride) is ionic? If so, would you expect a lattice forming?

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is an ionic salt, there is really nothing special about it. Like very many ionic salts (sulfates, carbonates, nitrates) it also contains covalent bonds. Like nearly all ionic salts, it is solid and crystalline.

Comment: For the rcord this compund is called *lithium aluminum hydride*.

Comment: @A.K. The IUPAC name is lithium tetrahydridoaluminate but yes everyone calls it lithium aluminium hydride or just LAH.

Comment: @A.K. Can you explain the difference between hydrido and hydride? Is it simply due to IUPAC and non-IUPAC uses?

Comment: @A.K. The postdoc in our group once said that LAH be the better name for the solid form since it never is pure $\ce{Li[AlH4]}$ — but that if you are dealing with exactly that, call it lithium tetrahydridoaluminate.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_aluminium_hydride - not sure if bonding of hydride bridges to Li is more ionic or covalent.

Comment: I think we should provide answers on higher level of abstraction then simply ionic or covalent.